# How should doctools be used with a standard class?

Tags: documentation

I am exploring the possibility of using `doctools` to document a package. According to the documentation, it can be used either in a `.dtx` file, when `doc.sty` is loaded, or in an ordinary document, when it isn't. I'm trying the latter option.

Based on the example at the bottom of page 3 of the manual, I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  loadHyperref=true,
  createIndexEntries=true,
]{doctools}
\begin{document}
  aardvark
\end{document}
```

This failed to compile with an error complaining about the need for `textcomp`, so I added this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[%
  loadHyperref=true,
  createIndexEntries=true,
]{doctools}
\begin{document}
  aardvark
\end{document}
```

This does compile, but it produces a slew of warnings. The following are typical:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `draft' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 13.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `final' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 13.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `setpagesize' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 13.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `colorlinks' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 13.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagemode' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 13.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfstartpage' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 13.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfstartview' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 13.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfcenterwindow' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 13.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdffitwindow' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 13.


Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfdisplaydoctitle' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 13.
```

These results are from a compilation run using `TEXMFHOME=/dir pdflatex <filename>.tex` to eliminate any possible interference from a stray configuration file in my personal tree. (`/dir` is a non-existent directory.)

I realise these are 'just' warnings - aside from the initial error due to want of `textcomp` - but when an initial attempt to use a package yields an error closely followed by more than a dozen warnings before I even try to use it, it does not generally auger well.

Would it be best to avoid `doctools`? Or is it supposed to be used in a different way?